# ListPreference on tablet

Tags: android

I have a ListPreference on my android application.
On phone 2.3.4, it has the 'downward triangle with a circle' icon on the right. 
But when I run on the same app on Samsung Galaxy, it has no such icon. Can you please tell me how can I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: I think @slayton has the answer for you. But I would add it may be helpful if you include specifically which device you are dealing with. Samsung has chosen to brand several of their devices as "Samsung Galaxy" It is unclear if you mean one of the Galaxy S phones, or a Galaxy Tablet, and if you mean tablet whether you mean the 7" one or the 10.1" one, which could make a difference since only the bigger is on honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

The missing triangle is probably due to customizations that Samsung has made to Android. If you want to **force** the list preference to appear the exact same on each device regardless of the vendor you will probably have to subclass the `ListPrefernce` class and define exactly how you want it to appear, rather than using the definition that ships with the device.

**Update** I just noticed that you mention you are using a tablet in the title. I'm assuming you're using a Galaxy Tab 10.1 or 8.9. If that is the case the missing triangle is either due to  Honeycomb  or TouchWiz. If its a Honeycomb customization I wouldn't try to hack one in there.

It really is best for everyone if your app conforms to the UI standards put forth by the OS. Introducing inconsistencies in the UI tends to make users unhappy and can lead to interfaces that are difficult to use.